# jQuery Drag and Drop dynamic height

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

currently I'm creating a drag and drop application and using jQuery-ui.

My problem is when I added Container Element in my Area and inside the Container add RadioButtonElement. So when I have in MY Container only 1 or 2 Radio Element the Container height is by default 300px but when I add 3 or more RadioButtonElement inside of the Container, the Container height is still 300px and not dynamically, it does not change the height of Container.

Please have a look to the attachment.

[sample drag and drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOXFI.jpg)

Here is the jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/2sob2ctf/3/

Thank you
Usman

my code:

```
       var origin = 'sortable';
/*
    Schrittbox
 */
$(".builder .headbox").draggable({
    appendTo:".buildplace",
    connectToSortable:".buildplace",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    start: function () {
        origin = 'draggable';
    },
    stop: function (e, t) {
        bindDraggable(".headbox .content", ".radioContainer");
    }

});

$(".buildplace").droppable({
    accept: ".headbox",
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("schrittbox")
        if (origin === 'draggable') {
            ui.draggable.html($(".view",ui.draggable).html());
            ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
            origin = 'sortable';
        }
    }
}).sortable();
/* ende

 /*
 radioContainer
 */

$(".builder .radioContainer").draggable({

    connectToSortable:".headbox >.content",
    helper: "clone",

    start: function () {
        origin = 'draggable';
    },
    stop: function (e, t) {
        bindDraggable(".radioContainer .content", ".radioButton");
    }

});

/*
 radioButton
 */
$(".builder .radioButton").draggable({

    connectToSortable:".radioContainer .content",
    helper: "clone",

    start: function () {
        origin = 'draggable';

    },


});


function bindDraggable(selector, accept){
    $(selector).droppable({
        accept: accept,
        greedy: true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            console.log("radiocontainer")
            if (origin === 'draggable') {
                ui.draggable.html($(".view",ui.draggable).html());
                origin = 'sortable';
            }
        }

    }).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem that I see is that you use `content` class for both the container and the child. I was going to suggest you adjust `height: 300px;` to `min-height: 300px;` to allow the box to grow and not be locked in. Since this would apply to both elements, it causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leveraging `animate()` in your drop. It has the advantage of taking additive values.

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading `+=` or `-=` sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

Example:

```
function bindDraggable(selector, accept) {
    $(selector).droppable({
      accept: accept,
      greedy: true,
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("radiocontainer")
        var count = $(this).find(".radioContainer").length;
        if (count > 2) {
          $(this).animate({
            height: "+=60"
          }, "fast");
        }
        if (origin === 'draggable') {
          ui.draggable.html($(".view", ui.draggable).html());
          origin = 'sortable';
        }
      }
    }).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
  }
```

Forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2sob2ctf/6/